# Python 2.7 Selenium unable to extract data

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to extra data by return error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\'searchpopbox\']"}' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpjVcHQR/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8444)
    at FirefoxDriver.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpjVcHQR/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8453)
    at DelayedCommand.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpjVcHQR/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10456)
    at DelayedCommand.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpjVcHQR/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10461)
    at DelayedCommand.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpjVcHQR/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10401)
```

My code is as below and I am trying to get the list from the link

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
url = 'https://www.bursamarketplace.com/index.php?tpl=th001_search_ajax'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
a = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchpopbox']")
print a
```

I am seeking your help to get the right xpath for the url.

Comment: The xpath is right but did you set up the browser correctly. Also if you want the text just use print(a.text).

Comment: could you elaborate more? How to make it work? the code fail at the `a = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchpopbox']")`

Comment: @ArundeepChohan how to know if the url is opened ? Now `a.text` not functioning as the code fail at  `a = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchpopbox']")` where as you confirm, the xpath is correct. But it still return the error

Comment: The url is correct and the xpath is correct. It works off mine without an issue. How did you set up your firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This gets all the listing for that table.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.bursamarketplace.com/index.php?tpl=th001_search_ajax") 
time.sleep(15)
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchpopbox']")
print(a.text)
```

Or without chromedrivermanager same thing applies to firefox

.Chrome(executable_path='absolutepathofchromedriver.exe')

Comment: How about with Firefox? COuld you show another solution with Firefox?

Comment: `profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)`

Comment: Edit the original post as I missed out a few lines of code for Firebox

Comment: I need to implement in Pythonanywhere which only provide old selenium package 2.33.0. If I upgraded it will break my other code as it is due to their system image. therefore, I have to use Firefox